# Download File from URL on ASP.net Server

Tags: asp.net

I have a small file that I want to place on an asp.net server which can then be downloaded. The file is to be placed on an ASP.NET server.

My confusion is about where I can put a file in an ASP.net project to have it accessible by URL?  I haven't written anything for ASP in several years and don't remember that much about it.  I'd like to be able to ftp a new file to the server from time to time as required.

Can anyone point me in the right direction on this?  Thanks..

Comment: Can't you just put the file somewhere on the web server and access it directly?  ASP.NET doesn't even need to be involved if you're serving a file from the file system.  Just like how images/CSS/JavaScript files are served, this would work the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say "ASP.Net", it sounds like what you really mean is "IIS on Windows". You don't even need to install ASP.Net on the server to make the file available. All you have to is install IIS and put the file somewhere in the wwwroot folder or another hand-configured location.

Comment: Thank you both for replying.  I was not putting the file in the wwwroot folder and it needed to have a proper extension (not the 5-character extension I was using).

So, it turned out to be trivial with a little guidance from you guys.  Thx..